# call function gives undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Hi everyone I am trying to build a chat app but I have a problem

this is my `getCollection.js` file that contains the request of getting the messages from firebase

```
import { ref } from "vue"
import {projectfirestore} from "./../../cons"
import { collection ,getDocs,query, orderBy} from "firebase/firestore"; 

const Doc = ref([])
const error = ref(null)
const getCollection = async (collectionName)=>{
    const collectionq = query(collection(projectfirestore,collectionName), orderBy("createdAt"))
    await (await getDocs(collectionq)).forEach(doc=>{
        doc.data().createdAt && Doc.value.push({...doc.data(),id:doc.id})
    })
    if (!Doc.value) {
        error.value = "could not fetch the data"
        Doc.value = null
    }
    console.log("docs.value",Doc.value)
    console.log("error].value",error.value)

    return { error, Doc }
}

export default getCollection
```

and as you see there is two `console.log()` at the end of the function
[image]

so it fetches the data correctly

now this is the `ChatWindow.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="chat-window">
    <div v-if="error">{{error}}</div>
    <div v-if="Doc" class="messages">
        <div v-for="doc in Doc" :key="doc.id" class="single">
            <span class="created-at">{{doc.createdAt}}</span>
            <span class="name">{{doc.name}}</span>
            <span class="message">{{doc.message}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import getCollection from '../composables/getCollection.js'

export default {
    setup(){
        const {error , Doc} =  getCollection('message')
        console.log("docskk.value",Doc)
        console.log("errorkk.value",error)
        return {Doc, error}
    }
}
</script>
```

the same here I have two `console.log()` and this is there values

[image]

I would mention that the 2 `console.log()` in `ChatWindow.vue` printed before those on the `getCollection.js`

the expected result is that it must print the message information of the user above the message text field

[image]

and I am sure that the component is placed in the View
as it is in this `Chatroom.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Navbar />
    <ChatWindow />
    <NewChatRoom />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue';
import getUser from '@/composables/getUser';
import { watch } from '@vue/runtime-core';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import NewChatRoom from '@/components/NewChatRoom.vue';
import ChatWindow from '@/components/ChatWindow.vue';

export default {
    components: { Navbar, NewChatRoom, ChatWindow },
     setup(){
      const {user } = getUser()
      const router = useRouter()
      watch(user,()=>{
        if(!user.value){
          router.push({name:"Welcome"})
        }
      })
    }
}
</script>
```

and when I try to put await before the function call

```
 async setup(){
        const {error , Doc} = await getCollection('message')
        return {Doc, error}
    }
```

it doesn't show the `ChatWindow.vue` component on `Chatroom.vue` view

Comment: use await when executing asynchronous functions
const {error , Doc} =  await getCollection('message')

Comment: it gives me this error Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: A:\vue\My work\chat-firebase\src\components\ChatWindow.vue: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (6:30)

  4 | export default {
  5 |     setup(){
> 6 |         const {error , Doc} = await getCollection('message')

Comment: use async setup() {

Comment: after adding async await the component doesn't show on the website but the values received correctly ,still not appear in the website

Answer (score 0):

You should use `await` when reading asynchronous data.

Use

```html
<script>
import getCollection from '../composables/getCollection.js'

export default {
    async setup(){
        const {error , Doc} = await getCollection('message')
        console.log("docskk.value",Doc)
        console.log("errorkk.value",error)
        return {Doc, error}
    }
}
</script>
```

then wrap it using defineAsyncComponent

```js
const ChatWindow = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('@/components/ChatWindow.vue')
)
```

read https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#basic-usage

Comment: i do the steps you mention , I add async ```setup(){         const {error , Doc} =   await getCollection('message')         console.log("docskk.value",Doc)         console.log("errorkk.value",error)         return {Doc, error} ``` and round the component with defineAsyncComponent  ``` components: { 
      ChatWindow:defineAsyncComponent(()=>{
        import('@/components/ChatWindow.vue')
      })
    }, ``` gives  this error ypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')

Comment: the data are now currect Doc and the Error so the two console.log that was broken now fixed but still now let me show them in the component